# How to Get Top Menu in Header as dropdown in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, header, toplinks, default.xml

Want to show top links as "DROPDOWN" in custom theme. Trying from many days but still no success.

Have to show "Sign In/Up" Link in toplinks when customer is not logged in.

After Customer Logged In "Sign In/Up" replaced with Customer Name or Email Id with a "on hover" "DROPDOWN" having the following links in that

"My Account"
"My Orders"
"Custom Link"
"Sign Out"

Please help me out.

Reference for the above question

[image: Reference Image for the above links]

Comment: did you get any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a block class to achieve that.

First of all in your module's frontend `default.xml` layout file you have to add the following code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Your_Namespace\Your_Modulename\Block\Link" name="custom-link" after="my-account-link"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Your block class

```
namespace Your_Namespace\Your_Modulename\Block;
/**
 * Class Link
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 */
class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
    /**
     * Template name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Your_Namespace_Your_Modulename::link.phtml';  

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHref()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('custom/controller/action');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return __('Your custom link');
    }
}
```

Then you need also to create the template file we defined in the block class and add the following code

```
<li class="link custom">
    <a <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLinkAttributes() ?>><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()) ?></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Nikolas, Thanks for the reply but want to achieve dropdown with customer name or Email ID when customer is logged in. Before that only Sign In/Up Label will show up in top links. Then i need to show all the links{My Account, My Orders, Custom Link, Sign Out) in dropdown as shown in screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

First create `default.xml` in your module (I am assuming that you already know how to create module in magento2) with below path

`app/code/YOURNAME_SPACE/YOUR_MODULE_NAME/view/frontend/layout/`

and paste below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODUE_NAME\Block\TopLink" name="your-link-top">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">custom-path</argument>                    
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create Block `TopLink.php` in your module with below path,

`YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODUE_NAME\Block`

```
<?php

namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODUE_NAME\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context as TemplateContex;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class TopLink extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link {


    /**
     *
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * 
     * @param TemplateContex $context    
     * @param Session $session
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    TemplateContex $context, Session $session,array $data = []) {        
        $this->session = $session;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Render block HTML.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml() {
        if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }        
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
            return '<li><a ' . $this->getLinkAttributes() . ' >' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getLinkLabel()) . '</a></li>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    private function getLinkLabel() {
        return 'Custom Link';
    }    

}
```

Comment: Hi Keyur, I have created the same module as shown above but no custom Link is showing up in the TopLinks.

Comment: You are login into site because as per the comment you need this link after login. Also please clear your cache @Vinay

Comment: Hi Keyur, the link is showing up when customer will login. I want the Sign In/Up Link in Top Links, When customer Click on Sign In/Up and log in with that, then on the same place Customer Name Or Email Id will Appear with the DROPDOWN having like "My Account" "My Orders" and "Sign Out"

Comment: the code does the same thing

Comment: Hi Keyur Rechecked Twice, A Custom Link is coming Only when customer is Logged in.
How to show Sign In/Up and after login same link(Sign In/Up) replaces with Customer Name or Customer Email ID.
No Dropdown is not coming on hover with "Custom Links".

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an easier version (but I do not recommend it), using Object Manager. I modified the default.xml theme layout, where I included a phtml made by myself. You can create a custom phtml file, use it in the theme layout:

`<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" template="Vendor_Module::header-items.phtml" />`

instead of Vendor_Module you set the path to where you created the phtml file

And the header-items.phtml file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$context = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

$full_name = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
$first_full_name = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getFirstname();
$last_full_name = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getLastname();

if(trim($first_full_name) != '' && trim($last_full_name) != ''){
    $prenume_final = trim(strtoupper($first_full_name))[0];
    $nume_final = trim(strtoupper($last_full_name))[0];
}
?>

<div class="account-items">
    <?php if($isLoggedIn) : ?>
    <div class="isLogged">
        <a id="contul-meu" class="isLogged">
            <span class="text-header" id="name-account">
                <?php if (isset($prenume_final) && isset($nume_final)){ ?><?php
                echo $prenume_final.''.$nume_final; }?></span><span class="text-header"> Contul meu</span>
            <button class="account btn" id="contul-meu"></button>
        </a>

        <div class="meniuCont">
            <div id="funcCont" class="func-content">
                <span class="welcome-menu">Bun venit, <?php
                    echo $full_name ?>!</span>
                <hr class="hr-menu">
                <a href="/customer/account/">Sumar cont</a>
                <a href="/sales/order/history/">Comenzile mele</a>
                <a href="/wishlist/">Produse favorite</a>
                <a href="/customer/address/">Adresa</a>
                <a href="/customer/account/edit/">Informatii cont</a>
                <a href="/vault/cards/listaction/">Metode de plata salvate</a>
                <a href="/review/customer/">Recenzii produse</a>
                <a href="/newsletter/manage/">Abonare la Newsletter</a>
                <a href="/customer/account/logout/">Deconectare</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <a class="wishlist-block" href="/wishlist"
       data-bind="scope: 'wishlist'">
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!wishlist().counter == false }">

            <span class="counter-number">
                <!-- ko if: wishlist().counter -->
                    <!-- ko text: wishlist().counter.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: wishlist().counter -->0<!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="text-header">Favorite</span>
    </a>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="notLogged">
            <a id="contul-meu"><i class="far fa-user"></i> <span class="text-header">Contul meu</span>
                <button class="account btn" id="contul-meu-guest"></button></a>
            <div class="meniuCont">
                <div id="funcCont" class="func-content">
                    <a href="/customer/account/login">Autentificare</a>
                    <a href="/customer/account/create">Creare cont</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a class="wishlist-block" href="/wishlist"
           data-bind="scope: 'wishlist'">
            <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
            <span class="counter qty empty"
                  data-bind="css: { empty: !!wishlist().counter == false }">

            <span class="counter-number">
                <!-- ko if: wishlist().counter -->
                <!-- ko text: wishlist().counter.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: wishlist().counter -->0<!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
            <span class="text-header">Favorite</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "wishlist": {
                        "component": "Magento_Wishlist/js/view/wishlist"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

The next step is to create a CSS file with the menu classes and style them to make a dropdown.